# ESP8266-01 not responding to AT commands

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

my esp8266-01 is not responding to AT commands when i upload a blink sketch. I have to re flash it with some other firmware which i got from the internet to make the AT commands work i am new in ESP modules ...so is it common or have i done anything wrong the connections are shown below while flashing..
i used an arduino uno for flashing

TX-TX

RX-RX

VCC- 3.3v external supply

CH_PD-VCC(The CH_PD pin in my module was named as "EN")

RST-VCC

GPIO0-GND

GND-GND

the blink sketch in the example is working fine but not responding to AT commands while blinking...

this is what the serial monitor outputs at 115200 NL&CR

```
//some garbage values//    
       ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:1, boot mode:(3,0)

    load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
    tail 8
    chksum 0x2d
    csum 0x2d
    v614f7c32
    ~ld
```

Comment: Because you replaced the AT firmware with the blink sketch.

Comment: Cross site duplicate of [NodeMCU not responding AT after blink app](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/51529)

Answer (score 2):

You need to flash the ESP8266 with the AT firmware in-order to use the AT Commands.
Download The AT firmware and flash it using [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) or [NodeMCU flasher](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher).

Comment: NodeMCU flasher does not find my ESP-01 module which is connected to my arduino uno.